How to use a existing bucket for lambda deployment using CDK?
I am migrating my lambda applications from serverless framework to CDK. I am fairly new to CDK and wondering if I am missing something here. I have my lambda code in ./lambda/hello.js. I am trying to deploy this to lambda. In my previous successful deployments I have directly used Code.fromAsset which was uploading the zip file to a random S3 bucket created by CDK. I am now trying to upload this to a custom bucket which already exists. In serverless, I used to just mention this bucket name and my zip files used to get upload there and lambda deployment happened from that file.
import * as cdk from "aws-cdk-lib";
import { CfnSchedule } from "aws-cdk-lib/aws-scheduler";
import {
  Effect,
  PolicyStatement,
  Role,
  ServicePrincipal,
} from "aws-cdk-lib/aws-iam";
import { Construct } from "constructs";
import * as fs from "fs";
import * as dotenv from "dotenv";
import * as lambda from "aws-cdk-lib/aws-lambda";
import * as sqs from "aws-cdk-lib/aws-sqs";
import * as s3 from "aws-cdk-lib/aws-s3";
import * as lambdaEventSources from "aws-cdk-lib/aws-lambda-event-sources";
import * as s3Deploy from "aws-cdk-lib/aws-s3-deployment";
import { convertDayOfWeekToCron } from "../utils/convertDay";

// Determine which environment to use based on NODE_ENV, default to 'development'
const environment = process.env.NODE_ENV || "dev";

// Load environment variables from the appropriate .env file
dotenv.config({ path: `.env.${environment}` });

export class AwsCdkEventsStack extends cdk.Stack {
  constructor(scope: Construct, id: string, props?: cdk.StackProps) {
    super(scope, id, props);

    const lambdaBucket = s3.Bucket.fromBucketName(
      this,
      "LambdaBucket",
      process.env.S3_BUCKET || "",
    );
    const lambdaCodeAsset = new s3Deploy.BucketDeployment(
      this,
      "LambdaCodeAssetDeployment",
      {
        sources: [s3Deploy.Source.asset("./lambda")],
        destinationBucket: lambdaBucket,
        destinationKeyPrefix: "scheduler-service",
        exclude: ["**/*.ts"],
      },
    );

    // Define the Lambda function resource
    const helloWorldFunction = new lambda.Function(this, "HelloWorldFunction", {
      runtime: lambda.Runtime.NODEJS_20_X,
      code: lambda.Code.fromBucket(lambdaBucket, "serverless/hello.zip"),
      handler: "hello.handler",
      environment: {
        STAGE: process.env.NODE_ENV || "dev",
      },
    });

    const queueArn: string = process.env.SQS_ARN || "";
    const queue = sqs.Queue.fromQueueArn(this, "ImportQueue", queueArn);
    queue.grantConsumeMessages(helloWorldFunction);
    helloWorldFunction.addEventSource(
      new lambdaEventSources.SqsEventSource(queue),
    );
  }
}

Is such automated upload mechanism missing in CDK? What would be the recommended way of doing this? Please give me some pointers

Does it print any errors? Or are the files uploaded to S3, but it never triggers the Lambda Deployment?

First of all, the asset folder will be zipped and extracted into the S3 bucket by default. Since you need the actual zip file to be left in the bucket, you need to set extract to false.
Secondly, your asset file serverless/hello.zip will be uploaded to a scheduler-service prefix, as specified by destinationKeyPrefix. In the bucket, you should see your zip file have scheduler-service/serverless/hello.zip as the resulting key. That's what you need to pass to you lambda. Alternatively, you can use Fn.select(0, lambdaCodeAsset.objectKeys) so that the correct key is referenced automatically.
Additionally, it's a good practice to declare an explicit dependency from the lambda to the uploaded code, so that the function depends not only on the bucket, but on the code being uploaded to it.
BucketDeployment provides a deployedBucket prop for this purpose, so you would replace lambdaBucket in your Code.fromBucket call with lambdaCodeAsset.deployedBucket.
Resulting code:
const lambdaCodeAsset = new s3Deploy.BucketDeployment(
  this,
  "LambdaCodeAssetDeployment",
  {
    sources: [s3Deploy.Source.asset("./lambda")],
    destinationBucket: lambdaBucket,
    destinationKeyPrefix: "scheduler-service",
    exclude: ["**/*.ts"],
    extract: false,
  },
);

// Define the Lambda function resource
const helloWorldFunction = new lambda.Function(this, "HelloWorldFunction", {
  runtime: lambda.Runtime.NODEJS_20_X,
  code: lambda.Code.fromBucket(
    lambdaCodeAsset.deployedBucket,
    Fn.select(0, lambdaCodeAsset.objectKeys)
  ),
  handler: "hello.handler",
  environment: {
    STAGE: process.env.NODE_ENV || "dev",
  },
});

